# Applying a multi filter macro across multiple sheets within a workbook

Tags: macros, filtering

I have a file which has multiple sheets with data for each year. On a different sheet I have macro that filters data as per selection (multiple selection). the VBA code that I have works great when filtering for 1 sheet.I added a for loop to run the filter across the sheets but am having issue with it. I don't know how to let the code know to paste the filtered data from the next sheet(i+1) below the previous sheet's (i) filtered data. below is my code.
I goth this line of code (LastRow = Filter_sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1) from some random code but not sure how to apply this to copy the data

```
Sub Filter_Data()

Call deleterowbelow
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Filter_sh As Worksheet
Dim x1 As Variant
Dim lr1 As Long
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim x2 As Variant
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim x3 As Variant
Dim lr3 As Long
Dim Rng3 As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim ews As Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Set Filter_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter")

Filter_sh.Range("A7", Filter_sh.Range("A7").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Clear
For i = 5 To wb.Worksheets.Count
LastRow = Filter_sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Set ews = wb.Worksheets(i)
ews.AutoFilterMode = False

    With Filter_sh
        lr1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If lr1 > 1 Then
            Set Rng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lr1, 1))
            If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then
                x1 = Application.Transpose(Rng1)
                If Rng1.Count = 1 Then
                    x1 = CStr(x1)
                Else
                x1 = Split(Join(x1, ","), ",")
                End If
                ews.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, x1, xlFilterValues
            End If
        End If
        
        lr2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        If lr2 > 1 Then
            Set Rng2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(lr2, 2))
            If Not Rng2 Is Nothing Then
                x2 = Application.Transpose(Rng2)
                If Rng2.Count = 1 Then
                    x2 = CStr(x2)
                Else
                x2 = Split(Join(x2, ","), ",")
                End If
                ews.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, x2, xlFilterValues
            End If
        End If
        
        lr3 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        If lr3 > 1 Then
            Set Rng3 = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lr3, 3))
            If Not Rng3 Is Nothing Then
                x3 = Application.Transpose(Rng3)
                If Rng3.Count = 1 Then
                    x3 = CStr(x3)
                Else
                x3 = Split(Join(x3, ","), ",")
                End If
                ews.UsedRange.AutoFilter 6, x3, xlFilterValues
            End If
        End If
                
    End With
    
ews.UsedRange.Copy Filter_sh.Range("A7")
'Filter_sh.Range("A7" & LastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
ews.AutoFilterMode = False
Next i
End Sub
```